# Heroku Postgres DB error message in nodemon

Tags: database, heroku, error-handling, nodemon, heroku-postgres

I am using a Heroku db and I end up with this error message in my nodemon when I create a new table with sql tabs.

(node:28440) DeprecationWarning: Implicit disabling of certificate verification is deprecated and will be removed in pg 8. Specify `rejectUnauthorized: true` to require a valid CA or `rejectUnauthorized: false` to explicitly opt out of MITM protection.
Error: collision of objects.find with previously-attached function
    at /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/properties/node_modules/massive/lib/database.js:147:19
    at Array.map ()
    at Database.attach (/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/properties/node_modules/massive/lib/database.js:85:19)
    at /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/properties/node_modules/massive/lib/database.js:293:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

Up until the creation of a new table everything worked just fine. My workaround was to reset the Heroku db and start from a new db, but that's clearly not helpful if the error appears every time.
What's wrong and how can this be fixed?

Thanks y'all

Comment: hello! Did you manage to get to the bottom of this issue? I'm experiencing something similar and embarking upon the debugging challenge!